# Open new window after first

Tags: wpf

How can this be done

Login window appears first and if every thing is fine just close login window and open second Main window.
in win forms we modify program.cs but in wpf there is no program.cs.

Any solutions.?

Actully i did most of the work in the window that is created By default and now want to make it secondary(mean it should appear and then close when wanted giving control to new window)

```
   <Application x:Class="DevnMark_V1._0.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="Application_Startup">

    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>



 public partial class App : Application
    {
        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            var login = new MainWindow();
            login.ShowDialog();
            if (myAppSett.Default.validated == true)
            {
            var mainWindow = new DevNMarkMainWindow();              
                mainWindow.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
```

Login Window start XML

```
<Window x:Class="DevnMark_V1._0.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Progress"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="292" Width="563" WindowStyle="None" BorderBrush="#FF0A6277" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Topmost="True">
```

Exception occurs when i close Login window and occurs at point  `InitializeComponent();`of second window when it is viewed when it is going to be initilized

Comment: Instead of Application_Startup, does it work if you put that code in the constructor (public App())?

Comment: nops but worked when i changed to ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"

Comment: but when in this shutdowm mode after closing second window application did not closed like thread was alive

Comment: and adding  Application.Current.Shutdown(); to second window it solved but i dk this is correct way

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be no program.cs, but there is an App.xaml.cs in the default WPF program template and you can do the same thing there.

What you want to do is **remove** `StartupUri="LoginWindow.xaml"` from App.xaml and then modify App.xaml.cs's constructor to invoke your login window and your main window, like this:

```
public App() : base() {
    bool authenticated = false;
    LoginWindow login;
    while (!authenticated)
    {
        login = new LoginWindow();
        login.ShowDialog();
        authenticated = ValidUser(login.username, login.password);
    }

    MainWindow main = new MainWindow(login.username);
    main.ShowDialog();
}
```

The above example assumes you've added `username` and `password` as public properties to LoginWindow, and that you've modified MainWindow's constructor to take a parameter.

Comment: attached my app.xml now ho can i do that when one closes other opens?

Comment: Can i pass or do something that tells me that user has closed it simple or authenticated well? like we should pass variable in constructor?

Comment: Yep, see further edit for an example. You can modify the constructors of either window to take whatever parameters you like. When you call .ShowDialog() on a WPF window it'll block until the window closes, while .Show() will open the window without blocking the calling code.

Comment: Yes it helped me but the problem is that when i close login form application closes

Comment: Oops, you're right. Should work if you change main.Show() to main.ShowDialog().

Comment: is this code allright?
 var login = new MainWindow();
            login.ShowDialog();
            if (myAppSett.Default.validated == true)
            {
                var mainWindow = new DevNMarkMainWindow();
                mainWindow.Show();
            }

Comment: If you change mainWindow.Show() to mainWindow.ShowDialog() it shouldn't close, unless you overrode mainWindow.ShowDialog() to return immediately, like if you spawned another thread. Try putting a Console.WriteLine("This is the last statement in App()") at the very end of App's constructor to see if it's getting called prematurely.

Comment: added a breakpoint and it enters if and also executes the show

Comment: I'd need to see the code to figure out why it's closing prematurely.

Comment: I think there is some problem with shutdown property.I close login window by this.Close();

Comment: this time threw this exception The Application object is being shut down.

Comment: What line of code throws the exception? I need to see what the App() constructor looks like now

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem in this way:

1. I removed from App.xaml the `StartupUri="MainWinodw.xaml"`, leaving only `Startup="Application_Startup"`.
2. In `Application_Startup`, I IMMEDIATELY referenced both login and main windows:

   ```
   loginwindow Login = new loginwindow();
   mainwindow Main = new mainwindow();
   ```
3. I verified my Login, then closed the login window and opened the main window with a simple `.Show()`:

   ```
   Login.ShowDialog();
   if (!Login.DialogResult.HasValue || !Login.DialogResult.Value)
   {
       Application.Current.Shutdown();
   }

   main.Show();
   ```

No changes in `ShutdownMode`.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed OnExplicitShutdown method works and you can avoid explicitly shutting the app down in the second window simply by opening it with ShowDialog followed by this.Shutdown(), all in App.xaml thus not interfering with the rest of the application.