# Show Dialog is not showing the dialog box

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am trying to find out reason why ShowDialog() is not showing the dialog box for me.
I have an application where I have a credential dialog box(A) for the user to enter credentials. And I have another dialog box(B) to display some custom msg based on the user's credential.
After the user enter's credentials in A, I am doing something with it.
when I am trying to show the msg in B, ShowDialog() is not showing dialog B.

Can you guys think of any reason?

Here is the code:

```
bool isInternetConnected = class.CheckInternetConnection(ref error);

if(!String.IsnUllOrEMpty(error))
{
                DialogBox dialogBox = new DialogBox();
                dialogBox.Title = "Credentials";
                dialogBox.State = DialogBox.States.NoFooter;
                dialogBox.ShowInTaskbar = false;

                CredentialsContent Credentials = new CredentialsContent();
                Credentials.ContentCompleted += new EventHandler<ContentCompletedEventArgs>(
                                                                    dialogBox.OnContentCompleted);

                dialogBox.MainContent = Credentials;
                bool? result = dialogBox.ShowDialog();
                hasAccess = result.HasValue ? result.Value : false;

}

 UpdateDialog updateDialog = new UpdateDialog();
                updateDialog.ShowModal = true;
                bool? isTrue = updateDialog.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Have you watched the execution of the program?  Is there some logic statement that is cause execution to pass over the ShowDialog call, such as an If or Select Case?  Is there an exception (even if it doesn't crash the program, check the output window).

Comment: I was debugging the program and it just passes the step showdialog() for dialog B step, instead of stopping there and showing the dialog.

Comment: @alice7 : Can you please post some code?

Comment: Show please code which executing the ShowDialog() method

Comment: And there was no InvalidOperationException sent to the output window?  Is this a Window object that you are calling ShowDialog on?  Can you past some code showing how it was instanced and the code around where the call is made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it resolved.
What was happening is that windows was treating the first window(A) as main window.When it was getting closed the next window(B) as inconsequential.
So even with showdialog() it was not showing it.

The trick was to define UpdateDialog() at the start of the application.
The same question is answered here:
[Open new window after first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053794/open-new-window-after-first)